# Optimizing table overview on an aggregate level when using cumulative requirements in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find the best way to get an overview of an aggregate overview that is being shown cumulatively, i.e. by deducting observations that do not fulfill the cumulative requirements in each of the steps.

This is the table script and sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE #Table_A(
   id           INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
  ,totalAmount  INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,requirement1 VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL
  ,requirement2 INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,requirement3 BIT  NOT NULL
  ,requirement4 VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO #Table_A(id,totalAmount,requirement1,requirement2,requirement3,requirement4) VALUES (1,6580,'GROUP1',100,0,'TEST');
INSERT INTO #Table_A(id,totalAmount,requirement1,requirement2,requirement3,requirement4) VALUES (2,3667,'GROUP1',100,1,'PRODUKTION');
INSERT INTO #Table_A(id,totalAmount,requirement1,requirement2,requirement3,requirement4) VALUES (3,2907,'GROUP1',100,1,'TEST');
INSERT INTO #Table_A(id,totalAmount,requirement1,requirement2,requirement3,requirement4) VALUES (4,5271,'GROUP2',100,1,'TEST');
INSERT INTO #Table_A(id,totalAmount,requirement1,requirement2,requirement3,requirement4) VALUES (5,91630,'GROUP1',200,0,'PRODUKTION');
INSERT INTO #Table_A(id,totalAmount,requirement1,requirement2,requirement3,requirement4) VALUES (6,9925,'GROUP1',100,1,'TEST');
INSERT INTO #Table_A(id,totalAmount,requirement1,requirement2,requirement3,requirement4) VALUES (7,4730,'GROUP1',100,1,'TEST');
INSERT INTO #Table_A(id,totalAmount,requirement1,requirement2,requirement3,requirement4) VALUES (8,5171,'GROUP2',100,1,'TEST');
INSERT INTO #Table_A(id,totalAmount,requirement1,requirement2,requirement3,requirement4) VALUES (9,1250,'GROUP1',100,1,'TEST');
INSERT INTO #Table_A(id,totalAmount,requirement1,requirement2,requirement3,requirement4) VALUES (10,11223,'GROUP1',100,1,'TEST');
```

This is the overview that I am trying to achieve:

```
+------+-------------+-------+-----------+
| step | totalAmount | total |  comment  |
+------+-------------+-------+-----------+
| 1    | 40282       | 7     | comment 1 |
| 2    | 30035       | 5     | comment 2 |
| ...  | ...         | ...   | ...       |
| n    | X           | Y     | comment n |
+------+-------------+-------+-----------+
```

Finally, this is the SQL code that I have done so far:

```
-- drop tables if they exists
drop table if exists #table_step1
drop table if exists #table_step2

-- select data from the different steps
-- select data step 1
select *
into #table_step1
from #Table_A
where
    requirement1 = 'GROUP1'
    and requirement2 = 100

-- select data step 2
select * 
into #table_step2
from #table_step1
where 
    requirement3 = 1
    and requirement4 = 'TEST'
...

-- aggregate the data for each step and use UNION ALL to get overall overview
select 1 as step, sum(totalAmount) as totalAmount, count(*) as total, 'comment 1' as comment
from #table_step1

UNION ALL

select 2 as step, sum(totalAmount) as totalAmount, count(*) as total, 'comment 2' as comment
from #table_step2 

UNION ALL 
...
```

Comment: What is the question? What you've tried seems to cover your needs. Provide an example.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis. Yes I am getting what I need but just asking if there is a better way to do this since I still have some parts that are duplicate code, and the SQL-script gets quite long when I have a lot of criteria.

Comment: I think the main reason you are struggling so much here is the design of the table is violating 1NF by having repeating groups.

Comment: @SeanLange can you maybe elaborate a bit more about how the repeating groups is a problem for me? I am not that familiar with database design.

Comment: Consider what a total nightmare this would become if suddenly you need to add three new requirements. You have to change the table and every query that touches it. If instead you had a related table with the requirements you could adjust the requirements at any time and everything would just work with a changing number. Here is a good article discussing 1NF. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form

Comment: @SeanLange I get your point. But would you be able to point me in the direction of how to do this for my problem at hand or just how to do this in general?

Comment: The real struggle to give you an idea is that your table is so generic I can't tell what it might be. And no idea why you have different datatype for each requirement. And where does the comment information come from? The comment isn't in your data.

Comment: @SeanLange yeah you are right but I have had to anonymise my data. However, the data and datatypes are actually in accordance to what I have in the database just with other names and values. But maybe you can point me in the direction of a generic example of what you mean; I have tried to search a bit on my own but honestly I am not really sure what to look for to get an idea of whether I can do it for my problem.

Comment: A generic example is in the 1NF link I sent yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

How about using [Common Table Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql) instead of temporary tables?

**Example:**

```
WITH STEP1 AS
(
  select id, totalAmount, requirement1, requirement2, requirement3, requirement4 
  from #Table_A
  where requirement1 = 'GROUP1' 
    and requirement2 = 100
)
, STEP2 AS
(
  select * from STEP1
  where requirement3 = 1 
    and requirement4 = 'TEST'

)
, STEP3 AS
(
  select * from STEP2
  where totalAmount >= 5000
)
SELECT 1 AS Step, SUM(totalAmount) AS TotalAmount, COUNT(*) AS Total, 'comment 1' AS Comment
FROM STEP1
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, SUM(totalAmount), COUNT(*), 'comment 2' FROM STEP2
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, SUM(totalAmount), COUNT(*), 'comment 3' FROM STEP3
```

Answer (score 1):

My proposed solution to avoid duplicate code is to create a #step table where you will put for each of the n steps the requirement checks (NULL when not checked at each case), then use a while loop to insert into the final #results table what you need (practically each while iteration is the same as one union all line)

```
create table #result (step int,totalAmount bigint,total bigint,comment varchar(max))

create table #step(
    step int
    ,comment_text varchar(max)
    ,requirement1 VARCHAR(6) NULL
    ,requirement2 INTEGER  NULL
    ,requirement3 BIT  NULL
    ,requirement4 VARCHAR(10) NULL)

-- Note: initially you have NOT NULL on all requirements: So you can use NULL when a step does not need to check the requirement
insert #step values 
    (1,'comment 1','GROUP1',100,NULL,NULL),
    (2,'comment 2','GROUP1',NULL,1,'TEST')

declare @step int=1

while(@step<=2)
begin
    insert #result
        select @step, sum(a.totalAmount), count(*) as total, max(s.comment_text)
        from #step s
        inner join #Table_A a on 
            (s.requirement1 is null or s.requirement1=a.requirement1)
        and (s.requirement2 is null or s.requirement2=a.requirement2)
        and (s.requirement3 is null or s.requirement3=a.requirement3)
        and (s.requirement4 is null or s.requirement4=a.requirement4)
        where s.step=@step
    set @step+=1
end
```

I tested this and its #result is in agreement with your spec (I assume that you omited requirement1='GROUP1' in step 2, though)

Comment: Don't forget to put the final value in the while loop. or actually you could use a select count(*) from #step....